# Image map with text display js function - some parts don't display

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, dictionary

There has to be a simple reason this isn't working, but validating the code doesn't show it up, and staring at it hasn't helped. Most of the text displays fine when you roll over the image hotspots. But not for the red ones labelled 1, 5, and 6.

[see posture image half way down page](http://www.briligg.com/sitting.html)

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@briligg - 
It's escape character issue; you are using **' character** (single quote) to enclose function parameter (which is text in your case). However you text contains additional ' character (single quote) for mentioned labelled text; you can escape this single quote character using **\' (single quote character prepended by backslash)**

Original:

```
writeText ('Low back - The way flat seats round our low backs is a major reason so many people eventually have weak low backs and experience pain there. It doesn't help that most people sit an awful lot. We are the first walking apes, our pelvis has been extensively modified to allow that to happen. Unfortunately, sitting with this modified pelvis hasn't turned out to be easy.')
```

Modified:

```
writeText ('Low back - The way flat seats round our low backs is a major reason so many people eventually have weak low backs and experience pain there. It doesn\'t help that most people sit an awful lot. We are the first walking apes, our pelvis has been extensively modified to allow that to happen. Unfortunately, sitting with this modified pelvis hasn\'t turned out to be easy.')
```